# Angularjs append values within angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Need a bit of help with angular and check boxes and how would put together one variable with all the checked values in. Here's what I have got so far but can't seem to figure out a good way on concatenating all the values which are checked so they can be shipped of to a REStful $resource. How would I get some variable or $scope item with all the checked values in it in the following format. e.g.:

```
types = Permanent,Contract,Any,Fixed Term
```

sample data of checkboxes ($scope.newJobSearch.type):

```
{
  "Permanent": "Permanent",
  "Contract": "Contract",
  "Permanent or Contract": false,
  "Any": "Any",
  "Fixed Term": "Fixed Term"
}

<label class="checkbox-inline" for="{{jobType}}" ng-repeat="jobType in jobTypes ">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{jobType}}" value="{{jobType}}" ng-model="newJobSearch.type[jobType]" ng-true-value="{{jobType}}" ng-click="jobTypesCheck()"> {{jobType}}
</label>

$scope.newJobSearch = {};

function searchJobs(newJobSearch) {                  
  angular.forEach(newJobSearch.type, function (value) {
    if (value != false) {
      $scope.queryTypes.push(value); //Dose not seem to work
      //Some var in here which contains all the string values e.g:
      //Permanent,Contract,Fixed Term
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question and the code... You are trying to make checkbowes based on the object you have on first line ?

Comment: No sorry the first values are actual the results of all the inputs in various checked positions.

Comment: When they are checked they are assigned to their values and the ones which are not false I would like to convert them to a string separated by ',' so it can be sent of to REST resource.

Comment: Where have you declared $scope.newJobSearch ?

Comment: Yeah I had declared it above

Answer (score 1):

**See this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt0dfpyy/)</kbd>**

You can use a combination of `ng-repeat` and `ng-change` for updating your result set :

controller :

```
$scope.result = {};

$scope.items = [
  { name: "Permanent", checked: false },
  { name: "Contract", checked: false },
  { name: "Permanent or Contract", checked: false },
  { name: "Any", checked: false },
  { name: "Fixed", checked: false }
];

$scope.updateResult = function () {
  $scope.items.forEach(function (item) {
    $scope.result[item.name] = item.checked ? item.name : false;
  });
};

$scope.updateResult();
```

html :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input ng-model="item.checked"
         ng-change="updateResult()"
         type="checkbox">
  {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code at all. Anyway, I think you're looking for something like :

```
$scope.jobTypes =  ['Permanent','Contract','Any','Fixed Term'];
$scope.newJobSearch;
$scope.newJobSearch.type = [];
$scope.newJobSearch.type.checked = $filter('filter')($scope.newJobSearch.type, {checked: true});
```

Then :

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="{{jobType}}" ng-repeat="jobType in jobTypes ">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{jobType}}" value="{{jobType}}" ng-model="newJobSearch.type[$index]" > {{jobType}}
</label>
```

You don't need a function to bind data to the model, as Angular will do it by itself.